# ¿Como evitar que se oscurezca el fondo en android studio cuando se abre el navigationView con el menu?

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment

como podrán ver en el titulo, es básicamente eso, como saben, cuando el menú lateral (NavigationView) se abre queda una parte del fragment que esta en el fondo (del lado derecho de la pantalla) que se oscurece.

La pregunta es: ¿Esto podría evitarse?, ya que necesito que esta sección no se oscurezca al abrir el menú.

Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes quitar el degradado al abrir el **`NavigationDrawer`**, utilizando el método **`setScrimColor`** que te permite cambiar el color .

Código para aplicar transparencia:

```
drawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```